# Why functions's this keyword is set to window but window does not have function as property

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
  var testFnk = function() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  console.log(window.testFnk);
  testFnk();
})();
```

The output of this code is:

- undefined
- Window

Can you explain why inside the function this refers to Window, but checking window.testFnk is undefined?

EDIT: As i'm looking at the answers, my question was not stated clearly. What I ment: why in both cases the logged values is either 'undefined' nor 'window'?

Comment: #2 of http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3. Note: The "*global object*" in browsers is `window`.

Comment: If you think of `this` as the "owner" of the function *(as some do describe it)*, then you'll need to adjust your thinking a bit. The `this` value of a function is a dynamic value that is set based on how the function is invoked. It doesn't necessarily have any direct relationship to the function. It's *sort of* like a variable that is set either implicitly *(like when you do `func()` or `obj.func()`)* or explicitly *(like when you do `func.call(obj)`)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in non-strict mode, `this` defaults to `window` in browser-land. In strict mode, it'll be `undefined`.

`window.testFnk` is undefined because you haven't added the `testFnk` method to the `window` object. You can either do this explictly by assigning to `window`, or implictly through an implicit global (which'll throw an exception in strict mode, FYI);

```
(function() {
  window.testFnk = function() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  console.log(window.testFnk);
  testFnk();
})();
```